# Rooting trouble - Using Odin3 but unable to flash device

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, odin

Rooting Method: mrRobinson

Phone: Samsung Galaxy SIII

Model number: SAMSUNG-SGH-I747

Android version: 4.1.1

Carrier: ATT

Downloaded: Odin307 and root66_ATT_I747UCDLK3.tar.md5

Sumsung Driver: Updated

Kies: Stopped and Disabled

What I did:

1. Extracted the root66_ATT_I747UCDLK3.tar.md5 from the .7z file I downloaded.
2. Used Odin, put phone into download mode [with phone off, hold vol. down + home + power ], connected to computer and opened Odin.
3. once in odin clicked the PDA field and selected the root66_ATT_I747UCDLK3.tar.md5 I downloaded.
4. Left Auto Reboot and F. Reset Time checked.
5. clicked start and...

Message in Odin:

```
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> root66_ATT_I747UCDLK3.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
```

Nothing else happens, click on Start again and "All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)" shows again.

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be the driver.  I went onto Samsung's website and re-downloaded the USB driver and re-installed it.  Everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on the Note 2 SGH-I747. Windows XP refused to recognize the device, unable to install hardware. I had reloaded the drivers a couple of times. Today I was charging my other Note 2 which was working correctly. XP recognized and installed it. Huh! I plugged the broken one in. It was recognized. Odin then worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, probably it came up because I had first time checked the box for re-partition. Then I unchecked it , did reset and start again, it was then I was getting the message "Success 0, failed 0"

I powered off the mobile and again put it in download mode and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

For those with this issue, my problem ended up being the usb cable.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I reinstalled the drivers and when it still wouldn't work, I hit the start button several times in a row and the it suddenly started.